# How to download artifacts from Artifactory Server

Tags: artifactory

We have a bunch of jars in the artifactory server (the free version).
How can we download all the jars in a single http request from it ?

Do we need to tar all the jars into a single tar file in order to efficiently download the jars ?

Thanks
Sincerely

Comment: How do you decide which artifacts to download? What do they have in common?

Comment: Hi JBaruch, thanks for answering. These jars are internally generated. We just like to dump them to Artifactory once generated/build. We're ant-based house, not Maven and not using ivy.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are the one who generates the files, you have two options:

1. As you said, generate the tar before uploading it. You'll still be able to search and browse the files inside it.
2. Write a [afterDownloadError user plugin](http://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/User+Plugins#UserPlugins-Download). Each time the user tries to access a url with `.tar` in the end, create the tar from the needed files and serve it.

Comment: the plugin solution is very nice. btw: using name "afterDownloadError" looks strange.

Comment: The Artifactory user guide/doc says Artifactory user plugin allows groovy to extend its functionality. What about the free version ?

Comment: The Artifactory user guide/doc says Artifactory user plugin allows groovy to extend its functionality for pro version. What about the free version with groovy to upload/download jars from artifactory ?